# Translation of "to hawk up a loogie"

Tags: перевод

This is an informal phrase. I can find both "hawk" and "loogie" in my English dictionary, but neither one is in my Russian-English dictionary.

I found the verb "плюнуть", but I'm guessing that means simply "spit".

Here are the definitions in my English dictionary:

> loogie: (noun) a lump of phlegm or spittle
>   hawk: (verb), to clear the throat noisily

Comment: [Харкать](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is [`отхаркивать`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), which stands for "шумно прочищать горло или носоглотку, выплёвывая мокро́ту":

> Васька счастливо заржал, закашлялся и отхаркнул зеленую мокроту.

Other alternatives would be [`выкашлять`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) (and [`выкашливать`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)) and [`откашлять`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) (and [`откашливать`](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)), like in phrases:

> Сегодня утром выкашляла желтоватый густой комочек слизи.

or

> Как правильно откашливать мокроту.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be very casual, then the most common would be `харкнуть`

"Он харкнул ему в лицо"
"Откашлялся и схаркнул на землю"

An informal and slightly incorrect translation of loogie would be `сопли` which is more like "snot," but is used to refer to that as well.

Comment: Another informal, but closer translation of "loogie" would be [*"харчок"*](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%BA)

Comment: @Vitaly I've also seen харча, is it also commonly used?

Comment: @CocoPop I haven't heard *"харча"* with the meaning of spit.  There are  common informal nouns [харч](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87) and [харчи́](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B8) meaning *"food".* There is a derived verb [харчить / схарчить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) meaning *"to consume food".* Is it possible that the word you saw is related to the latter group?

Comment: @Vitaly It was in a story I read: — Какого хуя в раковине харча? 
—  Мой косяк - я забыл смыть.